# "Этак" или "эдак"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно: "этак" или "эдак"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В русском языке допустимы оба варианта - по желанию автора.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна: два варианта, строгой регламентации нет.